# setting coefficients in linear system for $n-1$ pivots

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

> Question: Given a system of linear equations $$ax_1 + ax_2 + ax_3 = 2\\
> x_1+ ax_2 + ax_3 = 0\\
> 2x_1 + 3x_2 + ax_3 = 1$$ 
>   For what 2 values of $a$ will the system's augmented matrix have less than 3 pivots?

I'm not looking for an answer to the question, but I'm currently using trial and error to try and form a row $0\,0\,0\,0$, and was wondering if there's some conceptual understating I'm missing that would point to a more logical strategy for finding $a$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use algebra, and perhaps expansion by minors, to find the determinant of the matrix of coefficients

$$\begin{bmatrix}
  a & a & a \\
  1 & a & a \\
  2 & 3 & a \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I believe you get a cubic polynomial. Set the resulting expression equal to zero and solve for $a$. Check each of those solutions to see if the resulting original equations have zero solutions or infinitely many solutions.